# I can't pass Excel.Application as an object to a method

Tags: c#

An object reference is required for the non-static method ExcelParser.Program.releaseObject(object). I dont know why i get this error. I can't manage to pass Excel.Application, Excel.Workbook, Excel.Worksheet as an object to releaseObject method.
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


namespace ExcelParser
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp ;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/mmm/hello.xlsx", 0,    true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Console.WriteLine(xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1","A1").Value2.ToString());
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to release the Object " +    ex.ToString());
        }

        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    } 
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a non-static method from a static method.

Change:

```
private void releaseObject(object obj)
```

to

```
private static void releaseObject(object obj)
```